# MVC Why are extra characters in URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post

MVC 5.

Delete POST for deletion confirmation view

I was used to seeing URLs like

```
http://localhost:64740/Order/
```

and

```
http://localhost:64740/Order/Delete/2061
```

But now I see:

```
http://localhost:64740/%28S%28vq45x3gsflin11zvxcuueydg%29%29/Order/Delete/2061
```

I can't think why the characters are now present. Any idea why the extra characters are coming up?

The effect is that now I can't delete any records. The request just gets bounced back to the GET instead of the POST, negating the delete confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using cookie less session, so the session ID must be placed in the URL, If you perform a redirection by using URL Rewrite Module, the session won't work. So, you'll need to enable cookie to make the URL clean.

Comment: Ahh! The vendor had set up implementing sessionState as SQLServer for me. When I looked at the web.config  and there it was. Thanks - removed it. Now everything seems to work - and now I get the *real error* as to why the delete fails.. Thanks